# Strategies to modify huge database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-administration

I am testing different strategies for a incoming breaking change. The problem is that each experiment would carry some costs in Azure.
The data is huge, and can have some inconsistencies due to many years with fixes and transactions before I even knew the company.

I need to change a column in a table with million of records and dozens of indexes. This will have a big downtime.

ALTER TABLE X ALTER COLUMN A1 decimal(15, 4) --The original column is int

One of the initial ideas (**Now I know this is not possible**) <s>is to have a secondary replica, do the changes there, and, when changes finish, swap primary with secondary... zero or almost zero downtime. I am referring to a "live", redundant replica, not just a "copy"</s>

**EDIT:
Throwing new ideas:**

1. Variations to what have been mentioned in one of the answers: Create a table replica (not the whole DB, just the table), apply a INSERT INTO... SELECT and swap the tables at the end of the process. Or... do the swap early to minimize downtime in trade of a delay during the post-addition of all records from the source

I have tried this, but takes AGES to complete. Also, some null and FK violations make the process to fail after processing for several hours.
"Resuming" could be an option but it makes the process slower with each execution. Without some kind of "Resume", each failure have to be repeated from scratch

An acceptable improvement could be to IGNORE the errors (but create logs, of course) and apply fixes after migration. But afaik, AzureSql (nor SqlServer) doesn't offer an "ignore" option

2. Drop all indexes, constraints and dependencies to the column that needs to be modified, modify the column and apply all indexes, constraints and dependencies again.

Also tried this one. Some indexes take AGES to complete. But **for now seems to be the best bet**.
There is a possible variation by applying ROW COMPRESSION before the datatype change, but I think it will not improve the real deal: index re-creation

3. Create a new column with the target datatype, copy the data from the source column, drop the old column and rename the new one.
   This strategy also requires to drop and regenerate indexes, so it will not offer lot of gain (if any) with regards #2.

A friend thought of a variation on this, which is to duplicate the needed indexes ONLINE for the column copy. In the meanwhile, trigger all changes on source column to the column copy.

For any of the mentioned strategies, some gain can be obtained by increasing the processing power. But, anyway, we consider to increase the power with any of the approaches, therefore this is common for all solutions

Comment: You would lose anything that happened between the time you created the secondary copy and when you swapped them, which would be the same thing you would lose with the *big downtime*, so there would be no net benefit.

Comment: @KenWhite, the key here is that I'm referring to a synced replica, not just a copy. This means that all the record operations the primary should be on the secondary? So, at the moment of the swap, the replica is theoretically updated. But I'm afraid that such replica cannot be modified, because it would not be a replica anymore.

Comment: I don't understand your question - what does "change a column" mean? How many rows? What are the statements you've tried, along with their EXPLAIN if appropriate? What's the schema? As it stands, you're inviting opinion and hypothesis, rather than specific answers.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt, In this case, "to change a column" is to alter the table schema to give a column a different format. Like: ALTER TABLE X ALTER COLUMN A1 decimal(15, 4). The column was int, now it is changed. I should have provided that info from the start. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests and backups, we finally used the following aproach:

1. Create a new column [columnName_NEW] with the desired format change. Allow NULLS
2. Create a trigger for INSERTS to update the new column with the value in the column to be replaced
3. Copy the old column value to the new column by batches
   This operation is very time consuming. We ran a batch every day in a maintenance window (2h during 4 days). Our batch filled the values taking oldest rows first, we counted on the trigger filling the new ones
4. Once #3 is complete, don't allow NULLS anymore on the new column, but set a default value to avoid the INSERT trigger to crash
5. Create all the needed indexes and views on the new column. This is very time consuming but can be done ONLINE
6. Allow NULLS on the old column
7. Remove the insert trigger - start downtime now!
8. Rename the old column to [columnName_OLD], the new to [columnName]. This requires few downtime seconds!

--> You can consider it is finally done!

9. After some safe time, you can backup the result and remove [columnName_OLD] with all of its dependencies

I selected the other answer, because I think it could be also useful in most situations. This one has more steps but has a very little downtime and is reversible at any step but the last.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to update A LOT of rows as a one-time event, maybe it's more effective to use the following migration technique :

- create a new target table
- use [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-into-select/) to fill the new table with correct / updated values
- [rename](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rename-table/)  the old and new table
- create indexes for the new table

Comment: Sounds good, would it be too slow if I create the indexes before performing the inserts?

Comment: @zameb updating indexes can be slower, but... you can try it out

Comment: I really liked this approach, but I don't know how, the source table has some inconsistencies with the target constraints, throwing errors during the insert/into. Would be ideal to skip and log the errors for a post-fix analysis, but I don't see an easy way to do that

Comment: @zameb that's already your work to handle these.. I'd use [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) to handle non-confirming cases (null,empty value, ... whatever). You should know the business logic. I gave you a good answer based on initial question and provided information. I woudn't recommend to *skip* anything without knowing the consequences

Comment: unless I'm missing something, INSERT... INTO SELECT will fail in any of the mentioned cases. This wouldn't be a problem with the business logic, but the process itself. So, if a null, FK violation or any other problem occurs after 9 hours, it will have to be fixed and re-run the process from scratch. If this is the case, the solution will not address my problem

Comment: @zameb you may increase the disk IOPS temporarily that could increase the performance, if that's a bottleneck. I hope you don't run the statements inside a transaction. Issues with integrity were never mentioned. This is the way to migrate with the least downtime, but indeed it's as well all or nothing. The SELECT needs to process the whole table, you need to know your data. It will not work if you are still exploring data